# Silverlight: How do I disable to browser's refresh button?

Tags: silverlight

I'm working on a Silverlight application (i.e. no HTML content at all) and one of biggest complaints is that if the user accidentally hits F5 the application restarts.

So is there any way I can disable the Refresh button in the browser? Or at least handle F5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are couple of options

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/105879/243232.aspx

From link:

> One option is to hook into the window
>   object 'onbeforeunload' event and
>   prompt the user to confirm the
>   refresh/exit intent.   Here is a
>   simple example that could be defined
>   in your HTML markup or even emitted
>   from the SL app (if it has DOM
>   access):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Leaving or refreshing this page can result in data loss.";
}
</script>
```

Comment: That seems like a reasonable comrpomise to me.