# How can I disable F5 (refresh Browser) for Silverlight application without affecting closing?

Tags: silverlight, browser, silverlight-4.0

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673715/silverlight-how-do-i-disable-to-browsers-refresh-button) post and noticed that when I am closing browser or tab the message is showing as well. I need to disable the Refresh button or give some warning but problem with solution in that post is that it shows message when I close  browser.

Is there any way to show message only on refresh?

I know that there are some posts like this on stackoverflow.com, but none of them work for me. So this is not a duplicate question unless there is a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.onbeforeunload` from JavaScript (as noted in the post you link to) really is the only way this can be done in a cross-browser, cross-platform way, that I know of.

But that does end up getting triggered for F5.  That's just the way browsers work - they unload a page before reloading it, even in the refresh case.

Do you really find users hit F5 often enough for such a prompt to be a problem?

Comment: I don't know how often users will hit F5(if will at all). I need this to add stability to my application. It's not too critical for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to catch a key down event on F5?
If not with silverlight you can probably with a keyboard hook.

Comment: It is possible, but what if user don't press F5 but press Refresh button on browser?

Comment: True, didn't think about that, but atleast the F5 button is covered then :P

Comment: Even if it's possible today, browsers don't really guarantee this to my knowledge.  And it can be different per-browser or per-platform.  And as Samvel says, this doesn't cover the user hitting the Refresh button (which I'd think is more likely than an F5 keypress for most users anyway)